# STL map changed size automatically

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I've created a map mp and inserted just one key and value to it. When I call the DFS function and get into it, initially the map size is shown as 1. However after the first if condition in DFS, the map adds a new key-value pair {0,0} to the existing map and goes into the else if condition because now a key 0 exists. Here's the code I've written

```
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<bool> visited;
map<int, int> mp;

bool flag = true;

void DFS(int key)
{
    if (visited[key])
    {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }

    else if (mp.count(mp[mp[key]]) > 0)
    {
       
        visited[key] = true;
        DFS(mp[key]);
    }
}

bool canFinish(int numCourses, vector<vector<int>>& prerequisites)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++)
    {
        visited.push_back(false);
    }

    for (auto prereq : prerequisites)
    {
        std::cout << prereq[0] << " "<<prereq[1] << "\n";
        mp.insert({ prereq[0],prereq[1] });
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < prerequisites.size(); i++)
    {
        DFS(prerequisites[i][0]);
        if (!flag) return false;
    }

    return true; 
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> prerequisites{ {1,0} };
    std::cout << canFinish(2, prerequisites);

}
```

Comment: Do you realize that `mp[5]` will *add* `{5, 0}` to the map if `[5]` does not exist?

Comment: These are all true statements that you are making.  So nobody has to guess what your question is or ask what you might realize, can you [edit] this question to include a clearly-asked question?

Comment: Oh i did not know that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

`operator[]` for map will default construct any missing elements; see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) for this explicitly. To check if there is an element present in the map you have a few options:

- Use `if (map.find(elem) != map.end())`
- Use `map.at(elem)` and catch the exception that is raised if the element does not exist
- Use `if (map.count(elem) > 0)` to check the number of occurrences of the key in the map

I have listed these in (roughly) descending order of personal preference.

Comment: There is also the [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains) member function, but it requires at least C++20.

Comment: Ooh yes I still forget about some of the shiny new C++20 features; mainly because I won’t be able to use them at work for another 5 years :(